# Script dynamically placed inside an iframe doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, iframe

**Context**

I have an iframe on a page, and I'm dynamically inserting a script inside it so that the script will be sandboxed and unable to affect the outer page. I'm expecting the script to execute, but it does not. Why is this?

**Code**

```
var iframe = document.getElementsById('/* ... */').contentWindow.document;

var script = '<script>document.write("foo");</script>';
iframe.body.innerHTML = script;
```

When I do this, I can see the script element being correctly inserted into the iframe's body when I inspect the DOM. But the script is never executed. If I open Dev Tools and go to the Console tab and switch to the iframe's context and type `document.write('foo');` I see `foo` appear in the iframe. But why isn't the script executing once it's inserted?

Comment: Try `.contentDocument` instead of  `.contentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (if using jQuery)...

```
$('#iframe_').contents().find('body').append("My Js Code");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using jQuery is not an option, as it uses `eval` and I want to sandbox this completely to ensure the script does not run in the parent context at all, even for a millisecond. It seems like the only vanilla Javascript way to do this would be to do `document.createElement('script')` and then insert that script into the body with a call to `appendChild`. Even so, I tried doing that and the script still does not execute.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: I tried creating this one https://jsfiddle.net/7v5wwypz/ but it isn't displaying  correctly for some reason

Comment: hmm now it seems like it works if I do `iframe.open(); iframe.write... iframe.close()` Not sure why that wasn't working when I was doing it before.

Comment: You probably should just do `iframe.load()`.